# Fast Way to Open all files in a folder, refresh all files, SAVE AS all files

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 different folder locations a template folder that contains 40 template excel files, which contain premade formulas.. These files are saved as template_2D, template_3D ect, however 30 files depend on one file that will be open called 'srtData.xslx' and the other 10 pull data from the 30 open.

Then I want to refresh all (as all depend on one another) then I want to save all 40 files down in a different location with their name without the template. eg. 2D, 3D ... but in a different location and then close all template files aswell as these saved files. SO the template files will not have changed, all that will happen is the refresh version has been saved down in a different folder location.

I am very basic with VBA so bare with.

So far, all I have is

```
 Sub OpenAllWorkbooks()

Dim fldrpath As String

fldrpath = "R:\Sam\"

'Step 1:Declare your variables
Dim MyFiles As String
 'Step 2: Specify a target folder/directory, you may change it.
MyFiles = Dir(fldrpath & "*.xlsx")
Do While MyFiles <> ""
'Step 3: Open Workbooks one by one
Workbooks.Open fldrpath & MyFiles

'Step 4: Next File in the folder/Directory
MyFiles = Dir
Loop

End Sub
```

However I think by doing this I have no idea how I will save all in a different folder

Comment: Change `Workbooks.Open fldrpath & MyFiles` to `Set wb = Workbooks.Open (fldrpath & MyFiles)` and then simply use `wb.SaveAs path,fileformat` Where `wb` is declared as `Dim wb as workbook`

Comment: Thanks! But how to save them as the same name without 'template_'?

Comment: wb.saveas replace(path,"template_",""),fileformat  will just remove the word "template_"

Comment: You can use `Mid(FileName,10)` to get the filename without the `Template_` or use `Replace` as suggested by @HarassedDad if you do not have the "Template_" word more than once in the file name.

Comment: Ah incredible! I am testing it out now and post a solution ASAP (or an error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution I used, folllowing the comments above:

```
Sub OpenAllWorkbooks()

Dim wb as Workbook
Dim fldrpath As String

fldrpath = "R:\Sam\"

'Step 1:Declare your variables
Dim MyFiles As String
 'Step 2: Specify a target folder/directory, you may change it.
MyFiles = Dir(fldrpath & "*.xlsx")
Do While MyFiles <> ""
'Step 3: Open Workbooks one by one
Set wb = Workbooks.Open (fldrpath & MyFiles)
wb.SaveAs path,fileformat

'Step 4: Next File in the folder/Directory
MyFiles = Dir
Loop

End Sub
```